# Request Message Text From NSMutableArray of PNMessage objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, unrecognized-selector, pubnub

I am working on a IOS messaging app using PubNub. I am passing a list of `PNMessage` objects to an array (`channelMessageHistory`) using PubNub's history() api request. These objects are passed to a local storage array for future use, which includes displaying the message text in cells of a `TableView`. The only line of code I am struggling with is the following:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[[[Globals sharedInstance] channelMessageHistory] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] message];
```

Note: `channelMessageHistory` - the array of `PNMessages` as discussed

The error I am receiving is the following:

```
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10a644680
```

I know that the issue is that for each `PNMessage` object that the array (channelMessageHistory) contains, I need to request the actual 'text' message from each object (using message.message).

The following should provide a good example of the `message.message` usage.

```
PNMessage *message;
NSString messageText = message.message;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Show the full and exact error message about the unrecognized selector. The details matter.

Comment: History API return you an `NSArray` instance. Are you sure that you apply it to your `channelMessageHistory` not by calling `-addObject:`?

Answer (score 1):

When you see this kind of error, you should check the type first.

```
if([[[Global sharedInstance] channelMessageHistory] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
    // correct?
}

if([[[[Global sharedInstance] channelMessageHistory] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[PNMessage class]])
{
    // correct?
}
```